# how to merge manifest file with R.java file in android

Tags: java, android, xml, r.java-file

When I click on R.layout.something (In Android Studio with Ctrl pressed) it is redirecting to R.java file. Actually it should redirect to XML file. So I need to know how to merge manifest file with R.java file

Comment: Yes, normally it should jump to the XML file. What version of AS are you using?

Comment: @Egor I am using AS version 1.5.1

Comment: Is the layout file inside your project? Or is it inside a library, or the Android SDK?

Comment: @Egor Layout file is inside the project only